# How to create a background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of webdesign and am not completely not entirely sure how to create a full background image.

I am playing around with the warship.ts example on typescriptlang.org, and I am trying to add in a background photo of a battleship. Below is the code of the CSS file:

```
html 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-ms-content-zooming: none;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url(pictures/cats.jpg); //My code
background-size: cover;
}
body {
font-family: Verdana;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/*background-color: #b5caae;*/
background: url('img/bg2.jpg');
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 0px;
min-height: 480px;
min-width: 640px;
}
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 25%;
}
#boards {
width: 100%;
height: 75%;
}
.quadrant 
{
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
width: 40%;
margin: 2%;
vertical-align: top;
}
#banner {
font-size: 40pt;
font-weight: 800;
font-style: italic;
color: white;
text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
height: 100px;
}
#status 
{
width: 80%;
border: 1px dotted gray;
padding: 1%;
background-color: #CCCCCC;
height: 80%;
}
.board {
background-color: #111111;
border: 2px groove black;
height: 80%;
padding: 0%;
position: relative;
}
.cell {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
height: 10%;
width: 10%;
border: 1px dotted #A0A0FF;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
}

.notBombed {
opacity: 0.2;
background:  url('img/bg.jpg') repeat;
/*background-color: black;*/
z-index: 0;
}

.cellHit {
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: #C00000;
z-index: 2;
}

.cellMiss{
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: #008000;
z-index: 2;
}

.ship {
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
width: 10%;
height: 10%;
border-radius: 20%;
/*background-color: #FFFF80;*/
background: #666666;
border: 2px solid black;
z-index: 1;
-ms-touch-action: none;
}

.dropTarget {
background-color: white;
}
```

As an IDE, I am using Visual Studio 2015. From the examples I have seen online, I place the url image in the solution explorer, then I reference it in the html method, and then set the image as a color. However, whenever I try to run it, nothing changes. Is there something that I am missing from the code, or am I updating this in the wrong spot? Do I need to change the HTML/ts code?

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]. The code you've provided is neither minimal (vast amounts of irrelevant stuff) nor complete.

Comment: Do you want the image to take up the full screen?

Comment: `pictures/cats.jpg` — So your picture of a battleship is in a file called *cats.jpg*?

Comment: make sure your image file path is correct, because if you using external css file with another directory, you should go backward through it. so you write `background: url('../img/bg2.jpg');`

Comment: I want the image to take up the full screen yes

Comment: Did your background image is working?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to html background image in every resolution, try with this code

```
background: url(pictures/cats.jpg) no-repeat  fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

do this for only `body{}` sector. remove background images code from other sectors.

Comment: This code is working well, don't leave negative votes.

Comment: There's no significant difference between this and the code in the question. The question hasn't explained what the problem actually is (so isn't really answerable).

Comment: He's asking how to placed background image fully page. my code is will be shown how to set fixed background image.

Comment: The code in the question will already (aside from a syntax error that was probably introduced during the transcription process) create a full size background image. Your code does the same thing as the code in the question. You haven't fixed anything.

Comment: My IDE says that the webkit, moz, and o lines are not recognizable

Comment: Also if my code isn't producing the image, then how does it work?

Comment: The vendor prefix stuff is obsolete crap. It was used to trigger experimental versions of the property in older versions of browsers (intended for use in development, not production sites). They have standardised non-experimental implementations now so the vendor prefix stuff shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yes, but we should writing any other codes because there are more various browser we have. sometimes opera browsers working codes that not working in firefox.

Comment: @Sidath — No. You shouldn't use experimental properties in production. You shouldn't pander to obsolete versions of browsers which are no longer supported for security patches (and have a userbase as close to zero as makes no difference).

Comment: Yes... I've got it, Thank you Quentin for your advices, that more helpful to increase my knowledge.